# File.Exist() returns wrong value

Tags: asp.net, file

I'm am using Asp.net Mvc3!

I wrote following code to search my file into the folder :-

```
 string TrailorsPath =Server.MapPath( "/ePortfolio/"+cid+"/Icons/"+ fileName);
  if (System.IO.File.Exists(TrailorsPath))
```

But it always give incorrect result:

My file path is like that :-

```
"D:\SVN_HobbyHomes\HobbyHomesWebApp\ePortfolio\1\Icons"
```

Comment: What value does `Server.MapPath( "/ePortfolio/"+cid+"/Icons/"+ fileName)` return?

Comment: I don't see the file name in your example path, Also put a breakpoint and see the value of cid and filename

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the "~" at beginning of the path.

```
string TrailorsPath =Server.MapPath("~/ePortfolio/"+cid+"/Icons/"+ fileName);
```

Answer (score 0):

there can be multiple problems 
put a breakpoint on the line

```
string TrailorsPath =Server.MapPath( "/ePortfolio/"+cid+"/Icons/"+ fileName);
```

and check the value of `Server.MapPath( "/ePortfolio/"+cid+"/Icons/"+ fileName)`

and to begin with use this

```
Server.MapPath( "~/ePortfolio/"+cid+"/Icons/"+ fileName)
```